# Customize the login menu on Joomla

Tags: joomla, authentication

I'm trying to customize the login form on my joomla website. 
Problem I am having is:
1- In Menu - Subheadermenu - I added a Login Menu. I would like to customize that menu item. Where do I go to do this?

2- Do I need to apply a login module to this and how should I position this, because its a login form and not really a article.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

P

Comment: Thanks, so far I went to template manager and tried to edit the mod_login - default.php.

Comment: Then when I went to module position, I made a fake position so that the menu module would not take the position however even it's still not working.

Comment: You're talking about changing the com_users login view? That does not use a module, that is a straight layout and making an override for the view in your template will let you modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the templates/[your-template-name]/html folder, create the following directory structure:

com_users/login

Then copy the files default.php , default_login.php, and default_logout.php from the components/com_users/views/login/tmpl folder over to the login folder you just created under your template folder.

You can then modify the files default.php, etc... under your template folder to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this, quickly where can I find the components/com_users/views/login/tmpl. Sorry for all the questions, figuring this part out as I go along.

Comment: Under the root directory of your Joomla website.